# Meteor JS: Timing of Accessing MongoDB affects the result of the Access

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I have a collection in my Meteor JS app:

```
MenuItems = new Mongo.Collection('menu_items');
```

In my Template Helper file I access this collection:

```
Template.admin_menu_items.helpers({

  menuItems: function(){
    //return items from DB
    console.log('inside menuItems');

    snapshot = MenuItems.find().fetch();

    console.log(snapshot);

    return snapshot;

  },
});
```

Then in my html template file I call this helper:

```
{{#each menuItems}}
  {{#each items}}
    {{this}}
  {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```

Then in my Template rendered helper callback section I again access that collection:

```
Template.admin_menu_items.rendered = function(){

  console.log('Template.admin_menu_items.rendered');

  var snapshotRendered = MenuItems.find().fetch();
  //
  console.log(snapshotRendered);


}
```

If I refresh the page I get the following output:

```
inside menuItems                    admin_m...4d3e6ec (line 9)
[]                                  admin_m...4d3e6ec (line 13)
Template.admin_menu_items.rendered  admin_m...4d3e6ec (line 36)
[]                                  admin_m...4d3e6ec (line 40)
inside menuItems                    admin_m...4d3e6ec (line 9)
[Object { _id="nHZBfwAt64dwiPjCB",  items=[3]}]
```

What I would like to understand and ask about is: why is it that the first call to `MenuItems.find().fetch()` inside the menuItems helper and the first call to `MenuItems.find().fetch()` inside the Template rendered callback function returns a empty `[]` array when the MenuItems collection has documents inside it already???

Is it because my template and template helper files are deeper in the hierarchy of files and therefore is loaded earlier than my menu_item.js file that instantiates the `MenuItems` variable by:

```
MenuItems = new Mongo.Collection('menu_items');
```

How do I ensure that the MongoDB will return the right number of documents from the very initial call or access done to it???

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more to do with subscriptions and data-over-the-wire than it is to do with the load order of files. When you refresh the page, you get the template first and the data later, so the order of operations is something like this:

1. The template starts building itself without data, so the helper runs with an empty array
2. The template is finished building and renders, but without data it too has an empty array
3. The data arrives
4. The helper reactively re-runs with the new data, and returns a full array

The solution to this, if you need the data in the rendered callback, is to prevent this template from running before the data arrives. You can handle this with a router that waits on a subscription, or by checking the data and only rendering the template once the number of items is not zero, or by using the [Template.subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) function and guarding your template with an `if` statement until the data is ready.

On a side note, you may want to return the result of `find()` in your helper rather than `find().fetch()`, it'll work the same in an `{{#each}}` block, but with finer-grained reactivity as Blaze can iterate over the cursor itself. Unless of course you really need the array.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I ensure that the MongoDB will return the right number of documents from the very initial call or access done to it???

Well, in the Meteor spirit... **You don't.**

The whole thing about Meteor is reactivity. You don't want to have to *wait*  for the data to arrive to start rendering. It would mean that your user would be watching at a blank page for a while before seeing some action, because the page blocks rendering, *waiting in dark oblivion* for the full data.

Instead you go for reactivity. You execute [reactive computations](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker) which are executed immediately, then each time reactive data inside them updates. Helpers are reactive computations, Mongo cursors in Meteor are reactive data. Helpers are run initially (maybe returning nothing because the data hasn't arrived yet), then each time some new data comes in.

You have to take the case of "Nope, no data yet" into account when coding these reactive computations. For example, `if(someCollection.findOne())` would make sure that there is at least one document in `someCollection`.
In your case it may not really be useful though since [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md) handles cursors pretty well.